# Elasticsearch : Java Sprint Boot : Mapping results to clases

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, kotlin

I am receiving the following error and not sure why.  The error also shows me I am not getting the _id returned either.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2018-10-28T09:45:26.129+0000",
    "status": 500,
    "error": "Internal Server Error",
    "message": "failed to map source [ {\"meta_description\":\"Harry ollectables gifts\",\"body\":\"About us sDesign:\",\"title\":\"Harry Potter-Harry Potter nyl\",\"meta_keywords\":\"Harry Potter,\"}] to class Result",
    "path": "/search/harry%20potter" }
```

So in kibana(Elasticsearch) if I query the data it looks like:

```
{
    "_index": "burf",
    "_type": "pages",
    "_id": "https://www.ebay.ca/sns",
    "_score": 15.293041,
    "_source": {
        "meta_description": "With nearly one million Stores on eBay, you're sure to find your version of perfect.",
        "body": "Skip to main ",
        "title": "Search eBay Stores | eBay",
        "meta_keywords": ""
    }
},
```

My model in Spring Boot looks like:

```
@org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.annotations.Document(indexName = "burf", type = "pages")
data class Result(@Id val id: String,
                  val title: String,
                  val body: String,
                  val meta_description: String?,
                  val meta_keywords: String?) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So finding another example: the following model fixed this, however, **I still can't get the score**?

```
@Document(indexName = "burf", type = "pages")
class Result {

    @Id
    var id: String? = null

    var score: Float = 0.0f

    var title: String? = null

    var body: String? = null

    var meta_description: String? = null

    var meta_keywords: String? = null
}
```